# In Perforce, what changelist is assigned to a file after a resolve -am?

Tags: perforce

Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2013.2/938876 (2014/09/23)

My question is about what the resulting version number of a file would be after a "p4 resolve -am".  Let's say I have a workarea in which I unshelve changes to my.file resulting in my.file#8 but the workarea has my.file#10 and there are conflicts.  I do a "p4 resolve -am".  I'm seeing that my.file is still my.file#8.  Is that correct?  Is there a way to tell if this is really neither #8 or #10 but the result of the merge of the two ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A `resolve -am` modifies the contents of your working file (the one in your workspace), but does not create a new revision until you `p4 submit`.  It does not change the pending changelist that the file is open in, nor assign a new submitted changelist to it.

The way to see what merges have gone into the working file is the `p4 resolved` command.

The `p4 diff` command will show you the line-by-line diff between what's in your workspace and the corresponding depot version (so if you did an unshelve into an edited file followed by a merge, this will be a combination of whatever diffs are in the shelf and whatever diffs you may have introduced in your own workspace).  You can also specify a version argument to `p4 diff` to diff against arbitrary revisions (e.g. the shelved revision, an older depot revision, etc).

Comment: Thank You Samwise for your prompt and detailed answer !